# Google cloud function always receive / from API Gateway

Tags: node.js, api, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-api-gateway

Let's setup the basics:
I'm using Google Api Gateway with differents backends like Google Cloud Function.

First, I was parsing the `req` paramters with a `switch` statement on a header containing the original request url. (Very messy but working)

So I decided to use an express app instead for my cloud function.

But here is the thing: my functions always receive `/` from the gateway and generate raging errors like **CANNOT GET /** when my path is *https://mygateway/api/subservice/action*

So my question is: can I change the handling of the express app to parse my header containing the original request url and not the default path url?

Here is a part of my config:

```js
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "my API",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "basePath": "/api",
  "host": "mygateway.[REGION].gateway.dev",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/subservice/action": {
      "get": {
        "x-google-backend": {
          "address": "https://[REGION]-[ProjectID].cloudfunctions.net/[mycloudfunction]"
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "jwt_security": []
          }
        ],
```

Comment: From my understanding, you are getting an error when you're calling the Gateway URL but it's working properly when calling the original Cloud Functions URL am I correct? Please update your post and include the relevant part of your API config and how you're calling the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found on this question something similar that guided my search of the response [possible duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60711968/passing-path-parameter-in-google-endpoints-to-backend-not-working)

According [Google's explanation of path translation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#understanding_path_translation) when we use `x-google-backend`, the backend will only receive the basic request. we have to define with the parameter `path_translation` the behaviour we expect. In my case, I want to receive the same path so i use `APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS`